# Use python to choose from multiple established internet connections on Mac (Wifi vs. ethernet)

Tags: python, internet-connection

At work, I'm connected to both an internal internet service (through wifi) and an ethernet cable for external internet access. The wifi connection is the only way to connect to our internal databases or systems, but ethernet is what I need for internet browsing. Currently, by default I'm on the ethernet cable, but when I need to connect to our internal databases, I have to unplug the ethernet cable or go into my settings to change the service order to specifically use wifi (unplugging is much quicker).

Is there any way to specify in python to specifically use the non-default wifi connection when connecting to my sql server?

Answer (score 0):

Python can't determine how to connect to IPs, that is in the domain of the operating system, at a lower level than Python cares about. You have to convince your OS to do it. Note that, because of this, the method is necessarily OS-specific, so nothing in this answer will work on anything other than Mac OS X.

---

I am not 100% sure, but I think you can do it so that OS handles the situation automatically. Try this:

- Know the IP address of your database (e.g. 192.168.1.1)
- Find out what the connection is called (probably Wi-Fi):

  ```
  networksetup -listallnetworkservices
  ```
- Find the gateway that is taking you there (e.g. 192.168.1.254) and its subnet mask (eg. 255.255.255.0):

  ```
  networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi
  ```
- Set up a route so that your Mac OS will know to use that gateway for that address. This is kernel-level stuff so you need superuser access:

  ```
  sudo networksetup -setadditionalroutes Wi-Fi 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.254
  ```

If I am correct, you can now browse the web using your normal connection, and use the <strike>ethernet</strike> Wi-Fi to connect to your database, automatically without you having to do anything further.

---

Another way to do this, closer to the way you asked it, is to create two different [locations](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202480), with different service order; then you can switch between them programmatically using

```
networksetup -switchtolocation MyLovelyDatabase
```

You can get back to the default using

```
networksetup -switchtolocation Automatic
```

You can do this method from Python using `subprocess`.

Comment: `sudo networksetup -setadditionalroutes Wi-Fi 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.254`
1) which ip address do i replace with my DB address?
2) You mentioned using ethernet to connect to DB, but your instructions look like it's the other way around (which is actually what I want)

Comment: Fixed the typo. I used the example IPs from above ("Know the IP address of your database (e.g. 192.168.1.1)"), but the syntax is `-setadditionalroutes networkservice [dest1 mask1 gate1] [dest2 mask2 gate2] ... [destN maskN gateN]`. Note that I have never done this, and this is just from reading the docs, so I am not 100% sure about the first method. Please tell me how it goes :D

Comment: When i ran `networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi` I was given both IP address and Router address along with subnet mask. 

I tried the setadditionalroutes with the ip address and router address (separately) and unfortunately neither one worked :(

Comment: "router" should have been the correct one to use as "gateway". (BTW, you should clear the route table with `networksetup -setadditionalroutes Wi-Fi` (and no addresses) just in case previous entries messed things up. I'll be sad if it doesn't work...

Comment: just tried it again, and it doesnt work. Could be because I'm running python code on jupyter notebook? thanks anyway though!

Comment: If you were trying the first method, you can't `sudo` from inside the Python program. It should be done on the terminal before you start your Python program (I don't know if the changes persist after reboot or not). If you were doing the second method, it should work, because it's just like rearranging the service list manually like you did so far, and I have no idea why it would not.

Comment: i didn't sudo from python. i ran it from my terminal, and then made the connection (or attempted to) from python. I'll test the second method later